# Is there a way to do cumulative np.bitwise_or in pandas groups?

Tags: python, pandas, grouping

I'm looking to something equivalent to:

```
s.groupby(k).sum()
```

Comment: Can you post sample input data and desired output, it's unclear what you're asking here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At a guess, this may be what you are after

```
df.groupby(k).agg(lambda x: np.bitwise_or.reduce(x.values))
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried agg(bitwise_or.reduce) and got a cryptic error.

Comment: Was looking for about 6 hours to find an answer like this - thanks! I've already tried writing my own function that gets applied to every "groupbyobject", but couldn't get it to work. However, in my case I had to use `df.groupby(k).agg(lambda x: np.bitwise_or.reduce(x.astype(int)))`.